# Create a temporary URL from a temporary PDF generated from session data

Tags: php, javascript, session, url, session-storage

I have a website that creates a PDF which is generated after a user adds images to a shopping cart.

You can try it out here by hover over images and clicking "add to pullsheet", then clicking "create PDF" in the sidebar:
https://s140452.gridserver.com/property/4118

So that brings you to https://s140452.gridserver.com/create-pdf/ which is a pdf generated from  the shopping cart, which is temporary data stored only on the user's machine... in other words, you can't share it without downloading it and emailing it to someone.

Is there a way to store that generated PDF at a temporary URL so a user can share it directly after creating it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Either use a URL directly to generate the PDF in a GET request and let them share that URL, or store the PDF in the filesystem, associate an ID with it, and give the user a URL containing that ID.

Comment: Sounds great Igancio... could you elaborate on the second option a bit? Thanks!

Comment: Get a hash of the contents somehow, put the PDF in the filesystem based on the hash, and give the user a URL based on the hash.